# Laravel Multiple Image Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I need to download multiple images in a Laravel response download function without Zipper because I need to show images on a new page in Angular. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want images served by server?

```
public function get($path)
{
    $file = Storage::disk('s3')->get($pathToImage);
    return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
}
```